# import comments from facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I have a blog that I coded myself. I don't have a lot of comments, and some comment on Facebook, where I publish a link to each blog post.

Is there a way to "download" comments made on facebook for a specific URL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way in my opinion would be FQL. Have a look at the [Facebook Documentation about comments](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/). So in your case it would be something like:

```
SELECT post_fbid, fromid, object_id, text, time FROM comment WHERE object_id IN
    (SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url ='LINK_TO_POST')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you mean "download" as in storing on your local hdd, but you can get the number of comments on a url (when using comment-box on that page).

Try using: `<fb:comments-count href="YOUR URL HERE" class="">`

Comment: I would like to include them with the comments made on my website. That is, importing them into the "comments" table.